# Huawei Tool Converter Cannot Resolve Symbol 'xms'

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, android-studio-3.5.1

I'm using the HMS Toolkit- Converter to add HMS API to my app automatically. After it converts `import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;` into `import org.xms.g.analytics.HitBuilders;` it tells me that `Cannot Resolve Symbole 'xms'`. I also tried going to HMS repository and add the Analytics Kit then hit Apply but it gives me an error `HMS Analytics Kit  applyplugin dependence added failed:/Users`.....

How can I resolve the issue on 'xms' during the conversion? (I used Add HMS API conversion policy.)

Answer (score 1):

Is Cannot Resolve Symbol 'xms' displayed when you use the Add HMS API(HMS API First) or Add HMS API(GMS API First) function?
If so, check whether the following method could solve your problem:

1. Check whether your HMS Core Toolkit is the latest version. If not, [download the latest one](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Library/84324591).
2. After obtaining the latest version of HMS Core Toolkit, try again to generate the XMS code.
3. If the steps above do not work, try to use Sync Project With Gradle File.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try add the HMS toolkit to your application from android studio. I think you can solve the issue with it.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/95569931

Comment: Yes, I installed it using the Market Place.

Answer (score -1):

How to open a file with the suffix "XMS"?

Do you have to use  software?

The memory located after 1MB  called **extended memory**.

Generally, programs cannot directly use extended memory.

The usage of extended memory is supported by XMS (extended memory specification), so the extended memory is sometimes referred to as XMS.

Before using extended memory, you should add the command of `HIMEM.SYS` in the `CONFIG.SYS` firstly.

[Here is the link about what is XMS.](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_20864311/article/details/81319310)

[Here is the link reffering to the extended memory of Huawei mobile phone.](https://jingyan.baidu.com/article/375c8e1973690a64f2a229bb.html)